# Which is correct in the following sentences, them or ones?

Tags: meaning

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. I don't believe in UFOs, because I have never seen them.
2. I don't believe in UFOs, because I have never seen ones.

Comment: I don't believe in UFOs because I have never seen any.  Using "them" would imply they exist. "Ones" is just not comprehensible here.

Comment: But you could say "...seen **one**."

Comment: It's either *them* or *one*, but not *ones*.

Comment: Suggested migration to [ell.se]

Comment: Laure, flying objects that were unidentified have been seen, therefore UFOs **do** exist. The point in this subject is what people think they are. The use of the word *believe* here, is not appropriate because it means missing the point. A sentence that would be more appropriate would be something like: *I don't think that UFOs are alien space craft*.

Comment: @Tristan That is correct, and a good point. But people do use and understand "UFO" to be synonymous with "alien spacecraft". So while your sentence is more appropriate, the OP's sentence is not inappropriate (except in specific contexts in which this usage would suggest inexcusable ignorance).

Answer (score 2):

> *I don't believe in UFOs because I have never seen them

This phrasing implies that if UFOs did exist, there would be a definite, countable set of UFOs and that you could reasonably expect to view every member of that set.  If you were referring to a particular type of UFO, or to the specific UFOs that someone else claimed to have seen, then you could use "them".

> *I don't believe in UFOs because I have never seen ones

This is incorrect because the number "one" should not be pluralized.  (There are occasions when the word "one" is used as a label rather than as a number, for example asking "Do you have a couple of ones?" to indicate that the asker is requesting some $1 bills, but that's not the case here.)

> I don't believe in UFOs because I have never seen one
>
> I don't believe in UFOs because I have never seen any

Both of these are acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

"Them" is okay.  "Ones" is never correct because it is not a word, but you could use "one".

1. I don't believe in UFOs, because I have never seen them.
2. I don't believe in UFOs, because I have never seen one.

Expressing a quantity is irrevelant within the context of the sentence.  To remove attention from specifics about a quantity, use "any".

1. I don't believe in UFOs, because I have never seen any.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer "ones" meaning some UFO's. "one" would also fit meaning a single one.
I would not say "them" because you don't speak of a definite number of UFO's.

Comment: *Them* doesn't **seem** like a definite number...